# distribution of (inverse) distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $F: \mathbb R \rightarrow [0,1]$ be strictly monotonic increasing distribution function. The random variable $X$ has distribution function $F$ and the random variable $U$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. I want to determine the distributions of $F(X)$ and $F^{-1}(U)$, but don't know how to do that.

Can somebody help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $F$ a cumulative distribution function for $X$?

Comment: @Arthur - "distribution function" and "cumulative distribution function" are interchangeable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y = F(X)$. Then
$$\begin{align}
F_{Y}(y) = \mathbb{P}\left(Y \leq y\right) &= \mathbb{P}\left(F(X) \leq y\right) \\& = \mathbb{P}\left(X \leq F^{-1}(y)\right)\text{ since }F\text{ is strictly increasing, }F^{-1}\text{ exists} \\
&= F_{X}\left(F_{X}^{-1}(y)\right) \\
&= y\text{,}\qquad y \in [0, 1]\text{.}
\end{align}$$
The solution for finding the distribution of $F^{-1}(U)$ is similar.