# Uniform Distribution - Change of Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have been stuck on the following question

> If $X$ has a cumulative distribution $F(x)$, then show $Y = F(X)$ has a uniform distribution with $U(0,1)$.

I attempted to solve this problem by first finding the cumulative distribution function $F(Y) = P(Y \le y)$ and we sub in $Y$ to get $$F(Y) = P(F(X) \le y)=\int f(F(X)dx = F(F(y)) - F(F(a)) = \frac{y+2ab-a}{(b-a)^2}$$ I'm not sure how this result helps me at all so any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [distribution of (inverse) distribution function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054576/distribution-of-inverse-distribution-function)

Comment: Oh you are absolutely correct I should have looked deeper for this similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$F(y) = P(F(X) \leq y)=P(X\leq F^{-1}(y))=F(F^{-1}(y))=y$$

Notice that $y\in[0,1]$ as $F(X)\in[0,1].$